# Unable to install cordova in spite of setting all up and entered in system Environments

Tags: cordova, npm

I am somehow unable to install Cordova. I have installed everything else except the last part this. It shows this:

```
C:\nodejs\node_modules>npm install cordova
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.1"})
cordova@4.3.0 cordova
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── q@1.0.1
├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.3.0 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.
2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.0.11, dep-graph@1.1
.0, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, npmconf@0.1.16, through2@0.6.3, xcode@0.6.7, elemen
ttree@0.1.5, d8@0.4.4, request@2.47.0, glob@4.0.6, init-package-json@1.3.0, tar@
1.0.2, plist@1.1.0, npm@1.3.4, cordova-js@3.8.0)
```

Comment: Have you tried to run cordova-commands? When you type cordova into your shell there should be some recognition. But wanted seems to indicate to want newer npm-version to be installed.

Comment: Tried that but did not work as well.

Comment: Does command "cordova info" not work?

Comment: It says current working directory is not a cordova-based project

Comment: Somehow I can create this: cordova create helloCordova and it cvreates it and id "io.cordova.hello. cordova but when do a cordova info it is current working directory is not a cordova project

Comment: It is cordova-logic to tell it's users that current working direcory is not a project after entering cordova info. I wouldn't care about this. as soon as you are able to enter a cordova-command just like you did then cordova is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same problem. Reverted back to this [0.10.37](http://blog.nodejs.org/release/) maintenance release and installed Cordova again and it worked without throwing any errors. I guess its got to do something with Windows 8.1 OS.